# Eclipse: do not close missing (because of network resource unavailable) files

Tags: eclipse, settings

**Introduction:**

I work from my laptop in two different places and I use Eclipse in only one of them. I'm using network resource (SAMBA) to keep my sources and I'm completely fine with that setup except for

**The Problem:**

I do not like to close Eclipse even when I work from the place where I don't have access to those sources. From the other point, whenever I accidentally open Eclipse window it starts refreshing the project, considers all the open files deleted (as there is no access to network resource) and closes all the editors. How can I prevent that except for disabling auto-refresh completely?

**UPDATE**

I'm looking for a setting in either Eclipse settings or config files or whatever, but I'll accept argumentative "It's not possible" answer as well.

**UPDATE2**

Updated title to more detailed in an attempt to bring more attention to the question.

Comment: Mine does not close not found files. Which Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: 4.2.1, build id: M20120914-1800, Mac OS X 10.8. Should have mentioned this.

Comment: For those looking at this question: problem "solved" by changing OS and IDE. After all, I've never really liked Eclipse...

Comment: What IDE did you switch to?

Comment: Irfy: Windows 7/Notepad++. Not really an IDE in the true meaning of the word, but I wanted just some nice syntax highlight anyway.

Comment: It's a shame that there's still no way to do this.  I have a similar desire as the original poster.  I have my source on a web server where I do most of the development.  I don't want to have to sync the server on every change and so edit the files on the server (in a git-controlled folder)
When I leave home, I'd really like it if eclipse would just leave the files open and gracefully fail to save changes until I return and connect back to the network

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you simply use some sort of version control. :)

That way the files will always be on disk, meaning you always have access to them, no matter what, you won't have to use samba either and just made it alot harder for yourself to lose any changes you made to the code/versions you had.

If you worry about things not being automatically updated, you can run a cronjob that will automatically commit your changes to the repo on the server. (into an autosave branch for example).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't want to have those sources on local HDD in any way - neither checking them out from version control repo, nor syncing etc. I need to stick to network-based solution.

Comment: Sorry.. that makes no sense. :) Looks to me like your problem is created by your perspective on things, not eclipse. Have you looked at encrypted filesystems and googled for samba vulnerabilities? :D

Comment: I don't really want to get into details here, so you can consider that either a requirement or my personal whim :)

Comment: Anyway +1 as this requirement not explicitly mentioned in the original question and your answer provides a decent solution to original question.

Comment: Your project files are probably loaded in memory to your computer RAM right? So, make a RAM drive, and use it as storage to work locally with eclipse, then rsync it. Those files will never touch your hard drive, then...

Comment: Since you keep your notebook on all the time, doesn't the fact that all the files have to be in memory (for eclipe to be able to display them) trash your security in the same manner as having them on the disk; meaning already and eversince you started working with this setup?

Comment: you could go for cloud storage version of svn using dropbox or box, google drive ect... or just set up a project on source forge and only upload when you are happy with the revisions you have done. ideally you need some sort of SVN or you will have some sort of hassle in the future. version control is network based and a hell of a lot safer than storing it on a local hdd

Answer (score 0):

**"It's not possible" through eclipse**

You are looking for caching mechanism of deleted files when eclipse restarts, for that to happen you need to save some thing in your local or atleast make a duplicate copy in the network drive(for your security).

- **alternate approach one**

So if you still want to do this 
create a copy of your code under your name on the network and give rights to no one else so others wont delete it and you could use that as your work place. **and please make sure you don't delete your files from your workspace**

- **alternate approach two**

you could infact have your repo and checked out code both at network and use the checked out code directly from network for your coding purpose.

- **worst approach**

you could go on to the network drive history and recover the deleted files and get the code working in your local

**Update:**

again the solution is not possible in your case

1. when a file is missing from the list of opened items. when ever user access it, an popup is given to user to save the file.
2. since u don,t want anything to be saved in local, **you cant opt for saving the file in local**
3. since your are disconnected from network, **you don't have option to save on network also**.

But there is a possibility that the eclipse listener to detect missing file should be overridden somehow to use the cached version available with eclipse. And it should also detect when the file is available again and so on.. which i dont suppose is a good option considering the unwanted data that will be saved in cache just for your purpose.

Comment: The matter is I'm not looking for a way to keep the files after Eclipse _restarts_ (I do understand it will require having all the files locally). I'm not switching off my laptop at all and I'm not closing Eclipse at all. Eclipse just starts closing all the editors when I accidentally _activate its window_ while the laptop is not connected to network.